# how many ways are there to distribute 48 identical balloons to 7 children if each child gets at least one balloon

Tags: combinatorics

I understand how to get the generating function (g(x) = (e^x) - 1, I believe) but I am having trouble finding the coefficient. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Stars and Bars, $\binom{47}{6}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Each child gets at least one.

Comment: @almagest: Yes, that's what $\binom{47}{6}$ counted. If $0$ is allowed it would be $\binom{54}{6}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You are right, I was forgetting it was ${41+7-1\choose7-1}$.

Comment: @almagest: For some reason I think of the at least one to each as primary, and the $\ge 0$  as secondary. So I think of $48$ with possibly $0$ to some by adding $7$ balloons, giving at least one to each child, then taking away a balloon from each. Cruel.

Comment: @Rocho There is a Stars and Bars explanation here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781125/multichoosing-stars-and-bars

Answer (score 2):

Since the balloons are identical, what matters is how many balloons each child receives.  Let $x_k$ be the number of balloons distributed to the $k$th child.  Then we must determine the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 48$$
in the positive integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of six addition signs in the $47$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $48$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 10$, $x_2 = 5$, $x_3 = 7$, $x_4 = 9$, $x_5 = 6$, $x_6 = 8$, $x_7 = 3$.  Therefore, the number of ways the balloons can be distributed is the number of ways of placing six addition signs in the $47$ gaps between successive ones in a row of $48$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{47}{6}$$

**Note:**  The number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$
since a particular solution corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in the $n - 1$ gaps between successive ones in a row of $n$ ones.

Comment: This really helps, I think I was just over complicating the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let 0 denote balloons and 1 denote children. Then we would have 48 0's and 7 1's.

The question becomes how many ways are there to insert these 1's into the 0's.

The number of 0's separated by 1's is the number of balloons for each child.

For example:

If there are 4 children and 10 balloons, and we have a sequence like this:

0000110001000

That means 4 balloon for the first child, 0 for the second, 3 for the third and 3 for the fourth.

Go back to the question, there are $48+7-1\choose7-1$ ways to choose the position for all 1's, so that's $54\choose6$ total ways.

Comment: You overlooked the requirement that each child receives at least one balloon.